# use of Tesseract engine in emgu 3.3

Tags: emgucv

I download the v3.3 But the use of Tesseract engine seem changed from previous version, so the most online example don't work.

The method .Recognize() does not take input.

Does anyone has a working sample using v3.3.?

Answer (score 0):

Check it out here:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/9898ed2c-da3e-3cd0-0be0-13953bb21a2b.htm

From Emgu 3.3 you need to `tess.SetImage(img)` then `tess.Recognize()`. It returns 0 on success.